# how to automate retraining/deployment for azure machine learning designer

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently developing a machine learning solution on azure machine learning designer :
[image]

then i have created the real time inference pipeline :
[image]

the inference job is executed from ADF, the only thing, i would like to automate the model retraining/deployment but i can't see how.

Answer (score 0):

To retrain a model in the designer, follow these steps:

1. Create and publish a pipeline with an import data parameter to use your own data for re-training.
2. Once the pipeline is published, you can submit it with the data parameter from the portal or trigger it with a REST endpoint.

For a detailed guide on retraining models in the designer, check this [documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/v1/how-to-retrain-designer.md).

To deploy a model in the designer, follow these steps:

1. Register the trained model.
2. Download the `score.py` and `conda_env.yaml` files for the model.
3. Configure the entry script. (Optional)
4. Deploy the model to a compute target.

For more details, refer to this [documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/v1/how-to-deploy-model-designer.md).